# Apache Redirect Using %{QUERY_STRING} To Match A String Anywhere

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, query-string

I'm looking to do an Apache redirect using %{QUERY_STRING} but it simply isn't working.

I am wanting to redirect any web page query that has a string anywhere in the URL.  So for example:

http://www.domain.com/328kadf83/dkad83kd/test83283/

The string would be "test" as shown above.

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} test
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.other_domain.com/page.html [R=301,L]
```

What I am doing wrong in this case?  The main thing is - the redirect needs to match anywhere in the URL where the string "test" appears - and it will then redirect to a specific web page.

The other questions I've seen on here are specifically for a directory or those with variables after a page name.

Thank you!

Comment: Hmm - wondering if %{REQUEST_URI} should be used instead.  Just tested that and it possibly worked.  Trying a few more.

Comment: There is no query string in your example, so nothing will match %{QUERY_STRING} condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /test    [NC]
RewriteRule .*  http://www.other_domain.com/page.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The slash in `/test` assumes that test always comes after a slash, which it does in the OP's example, but if the intent of the phrase "...that has a string anywhere in the URL" really means *anywhere*, the slash should be omitted.

Comment: @David Ravetti Sure, and it is right in the question. But, the purpose of my answer was to point out that QUERY_STRING is not the right condition as there is no query, not really how to implement the regex. That was just an example. Thanks anyway for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply match it in the RewriteRule as follows:

`RewriteRule .*test.*  http://www.other_domain.com/page.html [R=301,L]`